# A word or term for: "in another person's body"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, expressions, phrase-requests

What would be the word or term to describe a person who found themselves in another living person's body or the name of the process that put them there?

I've recently had a couple of experiences while sleeping that were so real that they troubled me for months afterwards. I do not believe they were dreams. I dream often and these were nothing like a dream and I have found nothing to describe this. Please help...

Comment: Does this apply _only_ to dreams, or does it occur while awake?

Comment: From the title and first para, we could call it "Freaky Friday" if it were a TV trope. The rest of it indicates either a vivid dream, or some other psychological experience which we are not equipped to explain  here.

Answer (score 1):

The dreams could be wishful thinking, unconsciously you may be seeking to live a different life, to be someone else.

It could also be a signal that you are living a period of great stress, the dreams do not mean you *physically* abandoned your body and entered into somebody else's.

But depending on your personal beliefs there are a couple of expressions that interpret this type **out-of-body experience** (OBE)

> **[channeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediumship#Channeling)**
>   The other incarnation of non-physical mediumship is a form of **channeling** in which the channeler goes into a trance, or "leaves their body", allowing a spiritual entity to borrow their body, who then talks through them. When in a trance the medium appears to come under the control of the spirit of a departed soul, sometimes entering into a cataleptic state, although modern channelers may not. Some channelers open the eyes when channeling, and remain able to walk and behave normally.

from Dictionary.com

> [**incarnation**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/incarnation)
>   2. a living being embodying a deity or spirit.

From Merriam-Webster

> **[out-of-body](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out-of-body)**
>   relating to or involving a feeling of separation from one's body and of being able to view oneself and others from an external perspective.

Comment: In the meantime I'put a bounty on one of your old favorites.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an analysis from someone who has never experienced 'vivid' or 'lucid' dreaming...and a little like Madame Blavatsky

Comment: @Cascabel This answer sounds like it is supported.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not believe they were dreams.

But they were dreams. They are known as "lucid dreams": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_dream. They are not harmful but if you are worried, seek medical advice.

Comment: +1 , but not really... _lucid dreams_ imply a certain amount of control. This sounds more like 'vivid' dreaming.

Answer (score -1):

Body-mind swaps are an oft used device in science fiction. One place it was used was in Star Trek (Original Series) in the last episode, *Turnabout Intruder.* A character used a [Life-energy transfer](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Life-energy_transfer) machine to forcibly swap bodies with Captain Kirk.

In Star Trek: the Search for Spock, a Vulcan technique of [Katra](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Katra) is used to transfer a body with two minds into a soulless body of another.